# Can Visual Studio warn about typing violations in Python when the code contains type annotations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, type-annotation

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio 2019 so that it warns me when I am passing the wrong type of argument to a Python function, contrary to what the function's type annotation says it should receive?  For example:

```
def areaOfACircle(radius: float) -> float:
    return math.pi * radius * radius

area: float = areaOfACircle("three")   # oops...
```

In this example the `areaOfACircle` function uses the optional Python 3 type annotation syntax, as described in PEP 526.  I would like to receive a warning from Visual Studio when my code appears to ignore type annotations; in this case, that warning could help avoid a fatal error.  Of course, Python is a dynamically typed language, but part of the promise of type annotations is that IDEs can use them to spot potential errors in code.  I'm wondering how to turn that on in Visual Studio.

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Take a look at [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). It is a static type checker for python. There probably also exists a plugin for your editor/IDE.